# getting keyerror in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, keyerror

Im getting key error while parsing json file.

json fil
}

I call it here:

```
with open('config.json', 'r') as login_details:
           login_conf = json.load(login_details)
           #print config["Staging"]
       if env == 'Staging':
           self.driver.get(login_conf['env']['Staging'])
       elif env == 'QE':
           self.driver.get(login_conf['env']['QE'])
```

Error obtained is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "testdemo.py", line 9, in <module>
   driver = MSOSOLUTION.login.BrowserLogin('Staging')
 File "../lib/python/MSOSOLUTION/login.py", line 20, in __init__
   self.driver.get(login_conf['env']['Staging'])
KeyError: 'env
```

Can someone please explain how to solve key error ?

Comment: ignore QE, it doesnot go there, since the env is staging here...

Comment: If the error persists with the corrected json file we're missing something here. Please show us the rest of your class.

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. If that's the case, please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

some points to note :[Vidhya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9834021/vidhya)

1. json is missing `,` in between `user` and `env`
2. you can use `login_conf.get('env').get('qe', None)`
3. in config.json it is `QE` not `qe`

Comment: i have tried 1 , even in that it was not working...u can ignore 3rd case, becos it wont even go to QE

Comment: @Vidhya can you elaborate little more so i can help with

Comment: while parsing json file, iam getting above mentioned error, Key error.

Comment: Regarding 2: the `None` in the second `get()` is not needed, that's the default and will be returned implicitly if the name cannot be looked up. Also, the second `get()` will raise an AttributeError if 'env' cannot be found in the outer dict by the first `get()` which then will return the mentioned default `None`.

Comment: past the contents of  `self.driver`

Comment: @Vidhya do `print self.driver` before  `if env == 'Staging':` line and copy past the result here

Answer (score 0):

you for got one comma after `"user":{}`

and also change

```
with open('data.json') as data_file:
    data = json.loads(data_file.read())
```

use `json.loads` instead of `json.load`. In Python 3, `json.loads` takes a string parameter. `json.load` takes a file-like object parameter. `data_file.read()` returns a string object.

```
{
 "user": {
   "name": "username",
   "password": "password"
 },

 "env": {
   "Staging": "https://serviceconsole-stg.tivo.com/serviceconsole/login.action",
   "QE": "http://serviceconsolese01.tivo.com:9090/serviceconsole"
 }
}
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "testdemo.py", line 9, in <module>
   driver = MSOSOLUTION.login.BrowserLogin('Staging')
 File "../lib/python/MSOSOLUTION/login.py", line 17, in __init__
   login_conf = json.load(login_details(x))
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
got the above error

Comment: only mistake is in config.json file you forgot one comma, everything else is right

Comment: just copy my json and paste it in your config.json file

Comment: with open('config.json') as login_details:
           login_conf = json.loads(login_details.read())
           #print config["Staging"]
       if env == 'Staging':
           self.driver.get(login_conf['env']['Staging'])
still getting same error KeyError: 'env

Comment: can you print `login_conf.keys()`, you error meaning is there is no key named `'env'`

Comment: [u'user']
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "testdemo.py", line 9, in <module>
   driver = MSOSOLUTION.login.BrowserLogin('Staging')
 File "../lib/python/MSOSOLUTION/login.py", line 20, in __init__
   self.driver.get(login_conf['env']['Staging'])
KeyError: 'env'

Comment: only user got printed..:(

Comment: i don't think there is other problem  then json file. you don't you make another json file and use it.

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. If that's the case, please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.